# PHP / MYSQL UPDATE with a IN() clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Today I was trying to create a query in MySQL that would update all `invoice_numbers` which has an id within a string.

```
UPDATE userhour SET invoice_number='{$invoice_number}' 
 WHERE id IN (" . $userhoursString . ")";
```

All fields exist and the query also works, however I keep getting this error which I cannot get rid of:

> Database Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '1' at line 1
>
> Last Query content: 1

an echo on my browser gives me:
UPDATE userhour SET invoice_number='2016030953500' WHERE id IN (24)

Which runs perfectly in phpmyadmin, so i am completely lost at this.

///// EDIT     /////

```
Field                Type    Null    Key   Default    Extra
id                   int(11) NO      PRI   NULL       Auto_increment
project_id           int(11) NO      NULL  
payment_id           int(11) NO      NULL  
userhour_category_id int(11) NO      NULL  
minutes_spend        int(11) NO      NULL
description          text    NO      NULL
active               int(11) NO      NULL
invoice_number       varchar NO      0
date_created         datetimeNO      NULL
date_modified        datetimeNO      NULL
```

```
<?php
require_once("Classes/ini_classes.php");
$_SESSION["errors"] = "";

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    redirect_to('login.php');
} else {
    require("Classes/phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    error_reporting( 0 );
    define('EURO',chr(128));

    $customer_id    =   $Database->escape_value($_GET['customer']);
    $project_id     =   $Database->escape_value($_GET['project']);
    $vat_id         =   $_POST['vat'];

    // retrieve all necessary database information.
    $customer_result_set            =       $Database->fetchSingleArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id='{$customer_id}'"));
    $project_result_set             =       $Database->fetchSingleArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM project WHERE id='{$project_id}'"));
    $vat_result_set                 =       $Database->fetchSingleArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM vat WHERE id='{$vat_id}'"));

    // get all customer info in variables
    $insert_customer_name           =       $customer_result_set['customer_name'];
    $insert_customer_streetname     =       $customer_result_set['streetname'];
    $insert_customer_city           =       $customer_result_set['city'];
    $insert_customer_zip_code       =       $customer_result_set['zip_code'];
    $insert_customer_province       =       $customer_result_set['province'];

    // get all necessary project info
    $insert_project_name            =       $project_result_set['project_name'];

    // calculate the price variables
    $total_time                     =   $_POST['time_so_far'];
    $price_per_hour                 =   $_POST['price_per_hour'];
    $vat                            =   $vat_result_set['percentage'];
    $subTotal                       =   ($price_per_hour / 60) * $total_time;
    $grandTotal                     =   (($subTotal * $vat) / 100) + $subTotal;
    $grandTotalDisplay              =   number_format((float)$grandTotal, 2, '.', '');


    $date_today             =   strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $deadline_date          =   strtotime('+30 day', $date_today);
    $deadline_formatted     =   gmdate("m-d-Y", $deadline_date);

    // rwewrite the array to a string and then get all userhours associated.
    $userhoursToBill        =   $_POST['billed'];
    $userhoursString        =   implode(', ', $userhoursToBill);
    $userhour_result_set    =   $Database->fetchAllArray($Database->customQuery("SELECT * FROM userhour WHERE id IN ($userhoursString) AND invoice_number='0'"));

    $invoice_number         =   date('Ymd') . $customer_id . $project_id . date('s');


    // email to send to
    $email_to_send_to       =   $Database->escape_value($_POST['email']);
}

// create the PDF
    class PDF_receipt extends FPDF
    {
        function ___construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'pt', $format = 'A4', $margin = 40)
        {
            $this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $format);
            $this->SetTopMargin($margin);
            $this->SetRightMargin($margin);
            $this->SetLeftMargin($margin);

            $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);
        }

        function Header()
        {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
            $this->SetFillColor(36, 96, 84);
            $this->SetTextColor(225);
            $image = "images/logo-for-invoice.jpg";
            $this->Image($image);

        }

        function Footer()
        {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $this->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->Cell(0, 20, "Thank you for purchasing with us.", 'T', 0, 'C');
        }
    }


    $pdf =  new PDF_receipt();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetY(30);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(14);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(225);

    $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    $pdf->SetY(45);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->Cell(190, 7,  "Invoice for: " , 0, 1, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(135, 7,  $insert_customer_name, 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, 'Reniax communication solutions', 0, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(135, 7, $insert_customer_streetname, 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, 'Richterslaan 177', 0, 1, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);

    $pdf->Cell(135, 7, $insert_customer_zip_code. ', ' . $insert_customer_city, 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, '3431 AJ, Nieuwgein', 0, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(135, 7, $insert_customer_province, 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, 'Tel: 030-6300415', 0, 1, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 18);
    $pdf->SetTextColor('19', '141', '223');
    $pdf->Cell(0,15, 'INVOICE', 0, 1, 'L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 1,'', 'B', 1, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
    $pdf->Ln();

    // border fix
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 3,'', 0, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7,'Invoice number: ', 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, $invoice_number, 0, 0, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7,'Payment terms:', 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7,'Payment within 30 days.', 0, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7, 'Date: ' . date('M-d-Y'), 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, date('M-d-Y'), 0, 0, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7,'Bank account name: ' , 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7,'Rodney Wormsbecher', 0, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7,'Payment due: ', 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(55, 7, $deadline_formatted, 0, 0, 'L', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 7,'IBAN: ', 0, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $pdf->Cell(45, 7,'RABO NL00 1234 1234', 0, 1, 'L', true);
    // border fix
    $pdf->Cell(0, 3,'', 'B', 1, 'L', true);
    $pdf->Ln();


    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetTextColor('19', '141', '223');
    $pdf->Cell(110, 10, "Description", 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, "Date", 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, "Time", 1, 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, "Price", 1, 1, 'C', true);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(243);
    $pdf->Cell(110, 1, "", 'LRT', 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 1, "", 'LRT', 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 1, "", 'LRT', 0, 'C', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 1, "", 'LRT', 1, 'C', true);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255);




    // total width: 190
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($userhour_result_set as $userhour) {
        if (($counter % 2) == 0 ) {
            $pdf->SetFillColor(243);
        } else {
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255);
        }
        $pdf->Cell(110, 8, ' ' . substr($userhour['description'], 0, 63), "LR", 0, 'L', true);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 8, substr($userhour['date_created'], 0, 10), "LR", 0, 'C', true);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 8, ' ' . calculateMinTohours($userhour['minutes_spend']), "LR", 0, 'L', true);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 8, ' ' . EURO . number_format((float)( $price_per_hour / 60), 2, '.', '') * $userhour['minutes_spend'], "LR", 1, 'L', true);

        $counter++;
    }

    $pdf->Cell(140, 8, '', 'T', 0, 'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8,  ' ' . calculateMinTohours($total_time), 1, 0, 'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8, ' ' . EURO . number_format((float)$subTotal, 2, '.', ''), 1, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->Cell(140, 8, '', 0, 0, 'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8,  'VAT: ', 'T', 0, 'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8, ' ' . $vat . "%", 1, 1, 'L', true);

    $pdf->Cell(140, 8, '', 0, 0, 'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8,  'Total: ', 0, 0, 'R', true);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 8, ' ' . EURO . number_format((float)$grandTotalDisplay, 2, '.', ''), 1, 1, 'L', true);


    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Output('invoices/' . $invoice_number . '.pdf', 'F');


    // send the PDF through mail.
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer = "SMTP";
    $mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
    $mail->Port = "587"; // 8025, 587 and 25 can also be used. Use Port 465 for SSL.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
    $mail->Username = "rodney22@live.nl";
    $mail->Password = "rodney2802";

    $mail->From     = "rodney22@live.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Rodney Wormsbecher";
    $mail->AddAddress($email_to_send_to);
    $mail->AddReplyTo("rodney22@live.nl", "Rodney Wormsbecher");

    $mail->Subject  = "Invoice #" . $invoice_number . " - customer: " . $insert_customer_name . " project: " . $insert_project_name;
    $mail->Body     = "The invoice for " . $insert_customer_name . " project: " . $insert_project_name;
    $mail->AddAttachment('invoices/' . $invoice_number . '.pdf', 'invoice for: ' . $invoice_number);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $_SESSION['flash_message']      =   'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }


    // get all userhours and update their invoice numbers

    $sql = "UPDATE userhour SET invoice_number='{$invoice_number}'  WHERE id IN (" . $userhoursString . ")";
    echo $sql;
    $update  =  $Database->customQuery($Database->customQuery($sql));


    // when finished redirect.
    $log_message        =   "[" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "]  [ INVOICE CREATE ]  " . $invoice_number . " has been created. by " . ucfirst($_SESSION['username']);
    WriteToLog($log_message, 0);

    $_SESSION['flash_message']      =   $invoice_number . " has been created.";
  //  redirect_to("customer_view.php?project=$project_id&customer=$customer_id");
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB? As far as I know MariaDB is a NoSQL database.

Comment: Can you `echo` the query you're running and share the output please?

Comment: ^. Also, what is in `$userhoursString`? Also, beware of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @AndreFeijo MariaDB is a fork of MySQL that's intended to be a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Your SQL statement looks alright. Could you please share the piece of code that is executing this statement as well as some information about the table (type of the columns involved).

Comment: @ AndreFeijo - ups, MariaDB is the better and faster MySQL !!

Comment: i am sure you are overwritten query variable. there is no 1 in your query. so you have different variable or overwritten

Comment: _If_ it is a number why is it:  `invoice_number='{$invoice_number}' `  and not  `invoice_number={$invoice_number} `. Is apostrophe required **Edit:** looks like it's `varchar``

Comment: Invoice_number is a varchar(45), sorry i should have included that

Comment: i used php to do a var dump on $userhoursString, it returned :  string(10) "21, 23, 24"      which seems alright to me.

Comment: $update  =  $Database->customQuery($Database->customQuery($sql));      turned out that i called the mysqli_query method twice. anyways thanks for all the support guys, you're great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
$update  =  $Database->customQuery($Database->customQuery($sql));
```

You can spot it yourself now, isn't it?

There are two calls to `$Database->customQuery()`. The inner call runs the query and probably returns `1` (or `TRUE`). The outer call attempts to run the string `'1'` as an SQL query, hence the error message.

Change it to:

```
$update = $Database->customQuery($sql);
```